# Saving a Stack Snippet resets scroll to the top of the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

I've noticed while adding Stack Snippets or editing existing ones to answers, the scroll position is being reset to the top of the page when you click "Save and Insert into Post" to save your Stack Snippet.

This is a recent change, and it's really annoying to have to scroll or <kbd>PgDn</kbd> back down to wherever the post is (for popular questions with many answers, it can be quite a bit down the page). Clicking "Cancel" in the Stack Snippet modal does not reset scroll position.

Can this be fixed to maintain scroll position again on the post I am editing, please?

FWIW, I'm on Firefox 66.0.5 on Windows.

Comment: I've experienced the same problem in the latest version of Google Chrome, so this is definitely not a platform issue.

Comment: Confirmed this behaviour in Safari. Also in chrome clicking, the "run code snippet" makes the screen jump to the top.

Comment: This should be fixed now. Not seeing the auto-scroll behavior any longer.